# When I create UICollectionViewController with Xcode, there will be a reuse problem, but it won't happen if it's my own code

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

when i  CMD+N build a new UICollectionViewController

The layout confusion caused by cell reuse：

```
MyLayout *layout = [[MyLayout alloc] init];
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400) collectionViewLayout:layout];
self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 400);
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

This will work with the following code：

```
 MyLayout *layout = [[MyLayout alloc] init];
UICollectionView * collect  = [[UICollectionView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400) collectionViewLayout:layout];
collect.delegate=self;
collect.dataSource=self;
collect.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 400);
[collect registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellid"];
[self.view addSubview:collect];
```

Anyone who knows why, I would be very grateful！

Comment: There is no "reuse issue", you just implement the reuse, you understand how and why it's there, it's an optimization. Not using it is bad idea. Now it's unclear what's wrong with that code, seems more to be an layout issue than a cell one?

Comment: Thanks a lot！I thought I'd go check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks Larme！[https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvqNW.png)

I checked the code：

```
self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 667);
```

and the offset :

```
scrollView.contentOffset.y > (_nums+1)*667
```

That's the right size，Thanks a lot！
[image]